# testing the google +1 button using cucumber

Tags: cucumber, google-plus-one

How do you test Google +1 using Cucumber? I've tried manually testing the google +1 button by adding the code found here(im using the html5 version)

http://code.google.com/apis/+1button/

and it threw an error when I tried it. I changed the data-href to "http://google.com"(amazing how google.com only has 87 +1s. @_@ well not really surprising, since they don't have a +1 button on the homepage, but I digress) and it now works. So the question is, how do you test it on your local machine?

While I can live with knowing that pressing the plus1 button calls my callbacks, how do I test in cucumber that I liked a local/non-existent page? Is there a testing API for this?

Here's a sample of what I mean in cucumber steps:

```
When I go to the album "Lamp Girl" page
And I Google +1 the album "Lamp Girl"
Then the album "Lamp Girl" should have 1 like
```

Answer (score 0):

Surely you're just testing Google's code here? What's the point of having a test for this? What are you afraid could go wrong?

Comment: we're actually counting the likes in google+, fb and a self-made like system. so we need a db count of likes, which i hooked using a js callback when you click fb like and g+. that's what i was actually testing

Comment: You mean you want to do something like [this](http://www.thephpx.com/tag/google-1-callback/)?